# Creating command line alias for Java class in ANTLR 4 generated parser

Tags: java, windows, antlr, alias, antlr4

Below is a line of code I found in Chapter 1 of the "The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference" book.  This command is not working in Windows command prompt.  How can I correct this error so it stores an alias for the Tool?  I imagine the author forgot to include the alias in this line of code, but I don't know where it should go.

```
C:\source\antlr4\Hello>java -cp C:\libraries\antlr-4.4-complete.jar;%CLASSPATH% org.antlr.v4.Tool %*
```

Error:

```
error(7):  cannot find or open file: %*
```

In the book, the jar file is not on version 4.4, but rather 4.0.  That's the only difference.  Instead of typing the line below, I should just be able to type "antlr4" from the command line to initiate the generated parser to accept input.

```
C:\source\antlr4\Hello>java org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig Hello r -tree
```

I am following the Hello World grammar.

In UNIX, it looks like the equivalent is:

```
alias antlr4='java -jar /usr/local/lib/antlr-4.4-complete.jar'
```

Comment: Have you tried searching about Windows' cmd aliases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that you should exclude the quotes when defining an alias in Windows.  There is also a `$*` to accept parameters.

```
C:\source\antlr4\Hello>doskey antlr4=java -jar C:\libraries\antlr-4.4-complete.jar $*

C:\source\antlr4\Hello>doskey grun=java org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig $*
```